# jQuery bbq... where's the grill?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange, jquery-bbq

I was looking at the jQuery bbq plugin, and couldn't find any mention of `document.hash` anywhere in his code.

I assume getting the hash is at line [1094](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/blob/master/jquery.ba-bbq.js#L1094):

```
function get_fragment( url ) {
    url = url || location.href;
    return '#' + url.replace( /^[^#]*#?(.*)$/, '$1' );
};
```

And setting the hash at [818](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/blob/master/jquery.ba-bbq.js#L818) But why use those instead of `location.hash` ?

Also what's the deal with [this](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/blob/master/jquery.ba-bbq.js#L804):

```
jq_bbq.pushState = jq_bbq_pushState = function( params, merge_mode ) {
```

Wouldn't `jq_bbq_pushState = function...` be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your second point - the one with `location.hash`- I can't tell for sure, but earlier versions of browsers might have had problems with `location.hash`.
My *guess* is that the author needed to rely on the `hash` property so he implemented his own.
If you search google for [ie6 location.hash](https://www.google.ro/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=ie6+location.hash&btnK=Google+Search&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=97b986a923593356&biw=1920&bih=1019) you wouldn't have to dig for information to see that there are many complains.

Comment: Actually, pushState is a new browser history method, that allows you to manually manipulate the history and store the state of the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method

Comment: @WilliamGolden Sorry for the confusion, but I was only referring to the second point in the question; the one with `location.hash`. See update.

Answer (score 1):

document.hash does not exists, you can access the hash by document.location.hash.
The get_fragment function seems to do the same thing.
I'm guessing the author used a custom function because he didn't knew about document.location.hash.

```
jq_bbq.pushState = jq_bbq_pushState = function( params, merge_mode ) {
```

This adds the function to the jq_bbq namespace/object and also allows referencing it with the local variable jq_bbq_pushState.

Comment: `jq_bbq.pushState` one's global and one's local? Also Ben def knew about `location.hash`

Comment: It's not global, unless bbq is a reference to window, but i don't think that. ( i'm just deducting this from the code, i do not know the framework )
This might be the result of wanting to expose a private function trough the jq_bbq namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could use a plugin if needed. In WordPress look for the Plugins section and under "Add New" you can do a search for alternatives. Here is a sample result https://bestgrill.reviews/best-wood-pellet-grills/. You may be able to find a plugin to help you with your problem.